Traveling from place to place in 1530
I’m setting a story in a fictional version of Mugello, Italy in the 1530s. It’s a little more fantasy than history but I do want the place to feel real? And for people to recognize it if they’re familiar.
Anyway, I have a character who travels from Mugello to Bologna (89km) and am trying to figure out how long this journey would take by carriage in September. I am guessing (really guessing here) that this probably would not have changed all that much from the classical period?
I have a pretty good grasp of Florence to Mugello based on research, but I’m coming up short on Florence to Bologna, let alone Mugello to Bologna. And yeah, mountains. I’ll keep looking in the meantime but not sure what I’ll realistically find!

Depends. Do you want them to have stopovers or a hard slog to get there on a deadline?

I expect the good folks of this site are doing some research to help you out, but to make a point - this is a detail that's way, way, way, way, way beyond making your story "feel real." It's a detail most historians wouldn't know without looking it up. Your average reader is interested in the experience, not the specific facts, and the time you're looking for depends on route (I found three quickly), climate, quality of vehicle and animals, bathroom breaks.... This kind of rabbit hole goes pretty deep and I suspect you can't see light at this depth.

BTW, when you get a moment, read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to understand the limits of this site. Thanks.

this is probably a better fit for the history stack since you can just ask the underlying question.

Online mapping services will tell you how long (in hours) it takes today to get from one place to another walking. It'll be a pretty close estimate for historical long distance traveling speeds - as long as you don't need to carry a lot of heavy luggage, artillery, etc.

@JBH Knowing the exact answer is beyond what anyone cares about, but if it was a two-week journey and you describe it as taking 90 minutes, that's going to affect verisimilitude.

@Ray While I understand your point, no author would make such a ridiculous mistake. The point I'm making is if it was a two-week journey and you described it as taking twelve days, nobody would notice, much less care.

On top of the excellent point from @JBH, I feel compelled to point out that unless your character is very rich, he’s not riding in a carriage (and definitely not a stage coach like you or many of your readers probably think of when you hear the term carriage). At best he would be riding a horse, maybe with a cart, but more likely he would just be walking. And walking involves relatively easy math and doesn’t require knowledge of 16th century transport infrastructure to figure out.

You make good points. Mostly I am working out if a specific plot point even makes sense from a word building perspective, vs how I will describe the journey. I think what I have imagined is plausible, but I don’t want it to be distracting, even if the setting is a bit abstracted. Thanks to the answers here, I am going to shift things slightly.

Also apologies for missing that history note. Will get it right next time!

I for for a change really deeply appreciate this being asked. I am avid reader of fantasy and historical fiction and unrealistic or inconsistent travel times breaks my immersion much more often than one may think. I am really glad this was asked and answered here because thinking about travel times IS important aspect of worldbuilding.

@byMaelstromer I totally agree. I even asked a similar question here (https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/possible-distance-travelled-by-horse-over-6-weeks) some years ago in the same vein and for the same reason.

You might find this helpful Stanford Geospatial Network Model of the Roman World

There was no way to go directly from Florence to Bologna in a carriage before modern times. In 1530, a willful traveller who insisted on going straight from Florence to Bologna would travel 2 or 3 days cross-country on horseback or on a mule through the Giogo Pass (note: Italian Wikipedia) (elevation 882 meters).
In pre-modern times, vehicular traffic, such as carts or carriages, between Florence and Bologna would have to go either through Pisa, Genoa, and Piacenza, or else south on Via Cassia to Rome and then back north on Via Flaminia to Rimini and then on Via Emilia to Bologna. But as far I can guess there was extremely limited vehicular traffic between the two cities in pre-modern times. Normal people, even moderately rich people, did not do that.
Once upon a time there was a  Roman road linking Florentia and Bononia, modern Florence and Bologna, going through the Futa Pass (elevation 903 meters) and the Raticosa Pass (elevation 968 meters) in the Tuscan-Emilian Apennines. The Roman road branched off Via Cassia at Florentia, and went to Bononia through the valleys of Mugello (on the Tuscan side) and the Santerno (on the Emilian side). The Roman road, like most secondary Roman roads, was intended for infantry travelling on foot; it decayed to nothingness over the centuries, and the route saw little use until the 18th century, because of the steep approach to the Raticosa Pass.
If you can read Italian, the Italian Wikipedia article about the Futa Pass is very much better than the sorry English stub.
Eventually, a new road was built through the Futa pass in 1759; this road would eventually (in 1928) become the National Route 65 (note: Italian Wikipedia). Wikipedia says that opening the new road in the 18th century cut the travel time on horseback  or on a mule between Florence and Bologna from 2 or 3 days to one (long) day.
The lowest pass is at 882 meters above mean sea level. On the Tuscan side, Barberino di Mugello (note: Italian Wikipedia, because the English article is useless) is at 270 meter a.m.s.l., so you can expect a rather strenuos climb.
P.S. About that carriage: If you are thinking about something like a stage coach as we see in the movies, forget it. Such things existed in the late 16th century, but they were about as rarely seen as a Lamborghini car in our days, and only filthy rich people could afford them. The normal kind of carriage in the 16th century was basically a wagon with a rounded fabric top and no suspension, or at best suspended on chains or leather straps. Springs were introduced about two hundred years later.

I think it would be hard to get a better answer without waking someone well-traveled from that part of Italy from the 16th century...

Um yes this is incredible?! I do read Italian so that wiki page was very helpful. I knew someone was floating around out there who cared deeply about this and it is the reason I am taking this route so seriously! Even if fictional. Thanks so much for the thoughtful answer.

Depending on how non-historical OP wants to be, the Roman road having been maintained and improved and carriages being a bit more comfortable than they historically were could work.

Five Days
So, I live in NZ, we have lots of hilly country (also Hobbits, Dragons and strange people in robes telling you that you shall not pass). When you get out into the Wops (read out of the Major cities) - Most towns are about 20 km apart. Historically, this is because this is the distance that could be reasonably travelled by Horse in a day over normal Terrain (that is, not a pre-built road or track)
If you push it, 3 days is also pretty reasonable. Above that, you start to get into where you would risk the health of the horse to achieve it (which could be done if needed - you just have to be prepared to have a dead horse at the end)

It’s at least 110km of walking distance and some 1000m elevation change between Bologna and Firenze.
A reasonably fit human, horse or mule can hike 20 to 40km per day with some luggage for some days without needing a rest day. So it will take between 3 and 6 days. You could cut down to 2 days or even 1 day if you are really fit and pushing it and don’t have to worry about re-supply or bad weather.
